# Generics and Type casting

Tags: hacklang

Here is very simplified example:

```
function getList<Tx>():Vector<Tx> {

    $values = ['1','2','3','4','5'];
    $list = Vector{};

    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $list->add((Tx) $value);
    }

    return $list;
}
```

For instance I know that $values are numeric, derrived from database fetching results or whatever, but stored as strings. So I want to cast them as int through

```
Vector<int> $myList = $this->getList<int>();
```

but

> Object casts are unsupported. Try 'if ($var instanceof Tx)' or
>   'invariant($var instanceof Tx, ...)'. (Naming[2055])

So should I use two functions for different types in this case like `getListInt():Vector<int>` and `getListString():Vector<string>` or I do miss something?

Answer (score -1):

Just as a workaround, and not really a hacklang answer, but I would just try to solve that in mysql. Why not casting it directly in the mysql query?

```
SELECT CONVERT(field_as_string,UNSIGNED INTEGER) AS num FROM table;
```

Then your list is a list of integers, and you can just add it to a Vector.